# Looking for a phrase which would be something like 'under any criticism'

Tags: phrase-requests

I am translating a text, and looking for a phrase which would be something like ***'below any criticism.'***

Example:
**'The thing is in such a bad condition that it is *'outside any criticism.'***
(Meaning - any criticism wouldn't be strong enough; one cannot find the words which would be powerful enough; no point in criticism.)

Comment: '. . . defies criticism' ? The problem is to avoid ambiguity. 'Beyond belief' is idiomatic and unambiguous. 'Beneath contempt' likewise.

Comment: Thank you Nigel! Great suggestions! :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Beyond* is defined by Lexico (https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/beyond) in one of its meanings as follows:

> - To or in a degree or condition where a specified action is impossible

I believe you could say:

> - 'The thing is in such bad condition that it is beyond criticism.'

Comment: Wonderful! Thank you Mark and Petitrien! :-)

Comment: The snag is that 'He is beyond criticism' defaults to He is [considered, either because he's on a pedestal or because he has a big gun or lots of big friends] above criticism'. [Rolling Stone: Slay Anything: Is Beyonce Beyond Criticism?](https://www.rollingstone.com/music/music-news/slay-anything-is-beyonce-beyond-criticism-189653/).

Comment: @EdwinAshworth  The question is about a thing in bad condition.  I don't think your comment is relevant to that situation.

Comment: As the op wants want to say the thing is in a bad condition, Edwin Ashworth ‘s comment is entirely relevant, @petritien because, if you say ‘beyond criticism’ it will mean that the person is ‘so good, that no-one can possibly ever criticise him’ which is the opposite of what the op means to say.

Comment: @Jelila We're evidently talking at cross purposes.  To me nobody's being criticized but something is, like a dilapidated church say.  There's not enough of a context perhaps.

Comment: @petritien the same applies to an object being criticised.

Comment: @Jelila On further reflection, I think" beyond criticism" simply means it cannot be criticized for whatever reason, whether because it's too good (Michelangelo's David), too bad (Soandso's latest opus), too powerful (Stalin in Soviet Russia back in the thirties), too this ot too that.  I see it as ambivalent and that's what the lexicographers from Oxford Dictionaries imply in their Lexico definition.

Answer (score 1):

**Beggars belief**

Beggars belief is an idiomatic English expression that means that something is so bad, that you can’t believe it is even true how awful it is.

Examples:

- The terrible condition of the church roof, and how the pastor’s neglect let it get that way, beggars belief.
- It beggars belief that the restaurant could even dare to put that awful meal on the table
- The state of the road to Chipworth was disgusting - so broken and pot-holed as to beggar belief!

This phrase has the advantage of not accidentally conveying the opposite meaning, as some other options like ‘beyond contempt’ can be construed as the exact opposite ie - ‘flawless, perfect’, do (which has been explained clearly in the comments).

- it is generally used in English, politicians often use ‘beggars belief’ to express great disgust, disapproval or indignation about something or someone.

https://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/beggars-belief.html

Answer (score 0):

**The depths of depravity, execrable depravity, depths of depravity, marred**

I think to be clear in your translation, you’d be better to go for literally saying what it is.

Because of the points made by commentors that ‘beyond criticism’ and ‘beneath criticism’ etc. usually means ‘flawless’.

I think it unlikely that your text means ‘no point’ in criticism. More likely ‘depravity that is so bad it cannot be expressed in words’ or something.

https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/pretence